# Integer solutions to the equation $7x^2 = y^2+y+1$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

While investigating the related equation $7^n = m^2 + m+1,$ I managed to quite quickly handle the case that $n$ is even. If $n$ is odd, we may let $x = (n-1)/2.$ This now reduces to the question in the title of this post.

However, this is not really a reduction since the equation we obtain is more general. Nontheless, I recognize that solving problems often involves generalizing and solving the general problem from a higher vantage point. This is what I am trying to do here, and I would appreciate if anyone had any ideas on showing that $7x^2 = y^2 + y + 1, x, y > 0$ has only the solutions $(1,2), (7,18)$ (checked up to $y \le 100$).

Comment: Showing it has no solution in the integers? Isn't $(1,2) $ is a solution? $(7,18)$ is also solution.

Comment: @Mason Correct. I must've made a mistake when I originally looked for solutions. I will go back and check $y \le 100,$ then edit the post.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions. For example, $(62737,165986)$ is valid.

Comment: $(247,653)$ is another solution. I'm not doing anything too clever here: just using a [calculator.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2hzhalweng). There might be a general method of finding these solutions. it looks like you have something similar to but not quite Pell's equation.

Comment: @Mason You are much more skilled at using Desmos than I am. I typed $ \sqrt{(n^2+n+1)/7}$ and adjusted the slider until $n=100$; this would've never reached Rozenberg's solution.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Is there any way to generate these infinitely many solutions like we have for Pell's equation?

Comment: I think you can rewrite this equation as 28x^2 - (2y+1)^2=3. Then try using Pell's equation.

Comment: @user474986 We're almost there. Pell's equation has the form $x^2 - dy^2 = \pm 1,$ but we have $3$ on the RHS. What could possibly be done next?

Comment: Hint : Note that Pell's equation has |3|<√28. So every positive solution of it must be a convergent to continued fraction expansion of √28.

Comment: Refer : Theorem 7.24 Niven Zuckerman

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1049910

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's explain @MichaelRozenberg's strategy. Since $(2y+1)^2-7(2x)^2=-3$, we can find the solutions as follows:

- Find the [fundamental solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Fundamental_solution_via_continued_fractions) of $a^2-7b^2=1$: it's $a=8,\,b=3$.
- Do the same thing with $c^2-7d^2=-3$, viz. $c=2,\,d=1$.
- The most general solution of the latter equation is therefore $c+d\sqrt{7}=(2\pm\sqrt{7})(8+3\sqrt{7})^n,\,n\in\Bbb Z$. Now we just need the solutions with $c$ odd, $d$ even (but happily, those conditions are equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many solutions.

For example, $$x=\frac{(14-5\sqrt7)(127-48\sqrt7)^n+(14+5\sqrt7)(127+48\sqrt7)^n}{28}$$
and $$y=\frac{(5-2\sqrt7)(127-48\sqrt7)^n+(5+2\sqrt7)(127+48\sqrt7)^n-2}{4}$$

For $n=0$ we obtain: $(x,y)=(1,2).$

For $n=1$ we obtain Mason's solution: $(247,653).$

For $n=2$ we obtain: $(62737,165976).$

Comment: Are there any solutions that are not in this form?

Comment: @Display name There are more in the similar form.

Comment: For instance, switch $+\sqrt7$ for $-\sqrt7$, and vice versa, in the above formulae.  This modification gives $(7,18)$ with $n=1$.